# Newbie at dotNet dump analysis: dotnet-dump and clrstack -all

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, deadlock, dump

I am working with a multi-threaded application, which should reguarly be launching a thread, asking about the status of some "cars".
As one of the threads is still working (visible in Process Explorer and in the "Threads" part of the memory dump), I believe I'm dealing here with a deadlock.
In order to investigate this, I have downloaded `dotnet-dump` and I launched the following command in commandline:

```
Prompt> dotnet-dump.exe analyze "Dumpfile.DMP"
```

Once inside this `dotnet-dump` session, I have tried launching `clrstack -all`, as indicated in [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-deadlock?tabs=windows).

This, however, seems not to be working:

```
> clrstack -all
Failed to load data access module, 0x80004002
Can not load or initialize mscordacwks.dll. The target runtime may not be initialized.

For more information see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135652
> setsymbolserver -ms
Added Microsoft public symbol server
> clrstack -all
Failed to load data access module, 0x80004002
Can not load or initialize mscordacwks.dll. The target runtime may not be initialized.

For more information see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135652
```

I have followed the advise in that webpage but no success.
In top of this, I have different "mscordacwks.dll" files on my PC. How can I know which one to take?
Or even better, is there an easier way to investigate a dotNet memory dump for deadlock analysis?

**Edit:** For your understanding: I have the application open in Visual Studio, but I know from previous experience that tools like "Windbg" have commands like `!locks` which can be used for (dead)lock analysis. While searching on how to investigate (dead)locks in .Net, I stumbled upon the `dotnet-dump` tool.

Comment: Are you trying to analyze a dump file from a different system? Specifically a different OS?

Comment: Have you tried [opening the dump-file in visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2022) instead? That might be easier to use, especially if you can supply .exe/.pdb/source.

Comment: Why would you assume there are deadlocks unless you actually used locks? In any case, in Visual Studio you can open the Parallel Stacks window  to see what's going on with your application during debugging and all the active threads and their call stacks. You can use the Parallel Stacks window with dumps you load into Visual Studio as well. The best way to avoid deadlocks though is to *not* use locks or raw threads. Use tasks, channels, Dataflow blocks and concurrent collections instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos some pretty solid information there.